# using built-in local storage object:not getting null in the output when using remove

Tags: javascript, html, object, storage, local

I wrote a program for rock, paper, scissors with 4 buttons one extra for resetting. I wrote two functions one for computer move and one for player move. Along with that, it updates the wins, losses, and ties in the score object. so, I wrote the line to setItem in local storage for the score object in the playerMove function in the rock section. I wrote getItem for local storage at the beginning of the script.

I  wrote removeItem in local storage in reset button and then it did not show me null. what should I do to improve?

```js
const score =
  (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('score')));


function pickComputerMove() {
  const randomNumber = Math.random();

  if (randomNumber >= 0 && randomNumber < 1 / 3) {
    computerMove = 'rock';
  } else if (randomNumber >= 1 / 3 && randomNumber < 2 / 3) {
    computerMove = 'paper';
  } else if (randomNumber >= 2 / 3 && randomNumber < 1) {
    computerMove = 'scissors';
  }

  return computerMove;
}


function playGame(playerMove) {
  const computerMove = pickComputerMove();

  let result = '';
  if (playerMove === 'scissors') {
    if (computerMove === 'rock') {
      result = 'you lose';
    } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
      result = 'you win';
    } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
      result = 'Tie';
    }

    if (result === 'you win') {
      score.wins += 1;
    } else if (result === 'you lose') {
      score.losses += 1;
    } else if (result === 'Tie') {
      score.Ties += 1;
    }

    localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(score));

    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                        computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                        wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
  } else if (playerMove === 'rock') {
    if (computerMove === 'rock') {
      result = 'Tie';
    } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
      result = 'you lose';
    } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
      result = 'you win';
    }


    if (result === 'you win') {
      score.wins += 1;
    } else if (result === 'you lose') {
      score.losses += 1;
    } else if (result === 'Tie') {
      score.Ties += 1;
    }
    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                        computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                        wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
  } else if (playerMove === 'paper') {
    if (computerMove === 'rock') {
      result = 'you win';
    } else if (computerMove === 'paper') {
      result = 'Tie';
    } else if (computerMove === 'scissors') {
      result = 'you loose';
    }

    if (result === 'you win') {
      score.wins += 1;
    } else if (result === 'you loose') {
      score.losses += 1;
    } else if (result === 'Tie') {
      score.Ties += 1;
    }

    alert(`you picked ${playerMove},
                        computer picked ${computerMove},${result}
                        wins: ${score.wins},losses: ${score.losses},Ties: ${score.Ties}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>rockpaperscissor exercises</title>

<body>

  <button onclick="playGame('rock');">Rock</button>
  <button onclick="playGame('paper');">paper</button>
  <button onclick="playGame('scissors');">scissors</button>

  <button onclick="
            score.wins=0;
            score.losses=0;
            score.Ties=0;
            localStorage.removeItem('score');
            ">Reset score</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I expected a type error saying cannot read properties of null, but I didn't get anything on the console

Comment: Did you reload the page after removing the localStorage item? You only call `localStorage.getItem()` when the page loads.

Comment: I did not. I tried now and I refreshed the page after giving localStorage.getItem(), It worked!!! I got the error as null. Thank you. Can you please tell me why it won't work without refreshing the page?

Comment: how can I convert the pasted code into a snippet on stack overflow? does it get converted later into a snippet after posting?

Comment: I did not. I tried now and I refreshed the page after giving localStorage.getItem(), and then gave the localStorage.removeItem(), it gave me the error. It worked!!! I got the error as null. Thank you. Can you please tell me why it won't work without refreshing the page?

Comment: Code that isn't in a function is only executed once, when the page loads. So why would you expect it to happen without refreshing? It should also happen when you load the page the first time, unless you previously saved the item to localStorage.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do for how to create a Stack Snippet. Note that SO doesn't allow use of local storage in executable snippets.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I will take note of these things.